# CSS keep the background the same when making the screen smaller?

Tags: html, css

So, i have this background:

```
BODY {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-image: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/2gxn0gg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%; /* width, can be %, px or whatever. */;
  background-size: 70% auto; /* height, can be %, px or whatever. */;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vUN5A/

And when I minimize the screen (Make it smaller) I want it to keep hugging the top, or retain the size like it was maximized. How do i do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Your fiddle is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the description you list that you can use "%, px, whatever", but those actually do different things. "%" is dynamic, which means it is affected by your screen size or browser window. "px" on the other hand, is static, and won't change regardless of the screen size.

Therefore, you should not use "%" if you are not trying to change the size of the image. Use pixels instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `background-size` unless you actually want to change the size of the background. You're telling it to change the size of the background depending on the size of `body`: which changes when you make the window size smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/vUN5A/2/

```
BODY {background-color: #FFFFFF; background-image: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/2gxn0gg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;}
```

Comment: ~oh hey, it's you again~ And... if i took out the background-size then how would i get it to my prefered size, as that's not the actual size of the image?

Comment: Haha hi again :) Oh, so you were using `background-size` to stretch the image out to your preferred size, you just didn't want that to change on window size change? You can set it using `px` instead of `%` and it will stay the same then. However, you should probably just use a larger image? For the sake of image quality.

Comment: Well, it took me a long time to animate that, so... no :p, i'm not getting a new image. But, i am using px instead of %, someone else gave an answer. Thanks :3.

Answer (score 0):

use `width:auto` instaed of `background size`

```
 BODY {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/2gxn0gg.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center; 
width:auto; 
 }
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vUN5A/3/)